# Why python subprocess.Popen need close_fds parameter?

Tags: python, file, subprocess, popen, descriptor

Creating a subprocess seems to need to close some fd from caller, e.g., if caller opened fd 0,1,2(stdin,out,err) and fd=3(file named "a.txt"), and subprocess.Popen sets "close_fd=True", like

```
p=subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True,close_fds=True,stdout=None...
```

Does it mean:

(1) fd 0-3 are closed in subprocess?

(2) if fd 0-3 are closed, how could subprocess print lines to screen, or communicate its input/output with caller by :

```
p.communicate()
```

Just a bit confused. Explanations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only `3` is closed. From the [Popen docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html):

> If close_fds is true, all file descriptors except 0, 1 and 2 will be
>   closed before the child process is executed. (POSIX only).